# dplyr filter_at command with missing values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question on R and the dplyr command. I have got the following data frame df:

```
  ID   bank  type
  1    own   online
  2    own   offline
  3    NaN   total
```

Now I want to filter on the NaN value in combination with type "total". I know that I could easily filter  on the bank column only but I would be interested in combining two columns where one is NaN.
My command does not work

```
vec <- c("total)
l1 <- df %>% filter_at(vars(type,bank), any_vars(!(.  %in% vec) && (!is.na(.))))
nrow(l1)
```

The output should be "1".

Many thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use two different functions on different columns you should use `filter` here :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(is.na(bank) & type  %in% vec)
```

which can also be done in base R :

```
subset(df, is.na(bank) & type  %in% vec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(bank) & type %in% vec]
```